# UISegmentedControl inside UIStackView, segments text not centered - iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol, ios13

In iOS 13 UISegmentedControl design has been updated, but if you put a segmented control inside a UIStackView, the text of the segments is not centered.

This is what I see from the StoryBoard

[image: This is what I see from the StoryBoard]

This is the result on the running app

[image]

Comment: show me your constraints

Comment: The UI showed in the screenshots is an example, not my real UI, anyway the issue occurs also without constraints

Answer (score 3):

Bug report sent to Apple and solved with iOS beta 3.